# WP Contact Form 7 - Display [your-name] field on a separate page

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am really hoping someone can help. Searched my heart out, but didn't seem to find anything on this.

What I want to do is:

User is in a page where `cf7` is, and fills in details. I then redirect the user to a separate page using `on_sent_ok: "location.replace('pageurl');"`

How do I display the value of the user input name on the redirection page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to do any programming or need your client to be able to easily edit what is on each page of the form you can use the following plugin:

[Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/)

You can just add tags to the form builder that will separate pages. I chose this plugin because I wanted my client to be able to edit the form easily. If you use the code mentioned by [purvik7373](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5524992/purvik7373) you will need to make the updates to change form fields.

Comment: This was such a simple solution! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First change the `on_sent_ok` to:

```
on_sent_ok: 'my_custom_redirect();'
```

then create that `my_custom_redirect()` function in the page that displays the form:

```
<script>
    function my_custom_redirect() {
        var your_name = document.getElementById('YOUR_NAME_FIELD_ID').value;   // get value from your input field (YOUR_NAME_FIELD_ID) id
        var url = 'https://www.example.com/?name='+your_name+'';        // your redirection url
        window.location = url;
    }
</script>
```